# Which edition fits my notebook?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I have a new notebook:
with 
1.33G Duo Core
2G Memory
and 100g disk space
Which edition fits my computer?
Netbook or desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Netbook Edition is optimized for small screens (and using already Unity, that is coming in 11.04 Desktop Edition) and easy use for portability. I would use Desktop Edition for screen sizes larger than 12".